# Remove a string pattern from string

Tags: java

Let the string pattern be like `My place of birth is %s.`

Let the string be like `My name is MY_NAME. My place of birth is PLACE`

How to remove `My place of birth is PLACE` from the string, so that my final string after removal becomes `My name is MY_NAME.` ?

Example-1: Remove from last

```
Before Removal: My name is MY_NAME. My place of birth is PLACE.
After Removal: My name is MY_NAME.
```

Example-2: Remove from in between

```
Before Removal: My name is MY_NAME. My place of birth is PLACE. I speak ENGLISH. 
After Removal: My name is MY_NAME. I speak ENGLISH.
```

Example-3: Remove from start

```
Before Removal: My place of birth is PLACE. I speak ENGLISH. My name is MY_NAME.  
After Removal: I speak ENGLISH. My name is MY_NAME.
```

Is there any option in Java to perform this kind of activity? I could not find a relevant question or answer. If already present, please direct me to that.

Comment: So, `MY_NAME` and `PLACE` actually have different values every such string? Is the format always like this - especially the order of the sentences? Would it be enough to just delete everything after the first full stop?

Comment: As i understand your problem is PLACE is dynamic value hence you can't use replace here.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problem did you have?

Answer (score 1):

```
"My name is MY_NAME. My place of birth is PLACE".substring()
```

Comment: substring what? Just `substring()` does not compile, it expects arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Delete everything after the dot:

```
namePart = str.replaceAll("\\..*", ".");
```

This matches a literal dot and everything after, and replaces it with a dot, thus effectively deleting everything *after* the dot.

Comment: @user16320675 but the question is *equivalent to* "delete everything after the dot" given the example in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using [regex](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-regex):

```
String yourString = "My name is MY_NAME. My place of birth is PLACE";
yourString = yourString.replaceFirst("My place of birth is .+", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to select your desired string and then replace it.

```
"My place of birth is .+"
```